# How to compare the current UTC datetime with only the last three mint data?

Tags: python, datetime

my script is running comparing the current time with less than three minutes of data output and received the remaining data,

but how to get only the last 3 minutes, the most recent data from this remaining data and skip if the datetime does not match 3 minutes recently

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = [{'EventTime': '08/22/2022 07:45:10', 'Password_change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/22/2022 03:40:10', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/21/2022 07:32:23', 'Password_Change': 'Success'},
        {'EventTime': '08/17/2022 07:31:52', 'Password_Change': 'Success'}]

result = []
ref_time = datetime.utcnow()
# print(ref_time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
for item in data:
    event_time = item.get('EventTime')
    event_time_obj = datetime.strptime(event_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    diff = (ref_time - event_time_obj).total_seconds()

    if diff >= 180:
        result.append(item)

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

but this output is received after 3 minutes all output but i need to skip and i only need the latest output of 3 minutes

how to match with proper data and not just minutes

Comment: From your code it looks like you are selecting all the entries where `diff >= 180` (e.g. where the entry is from _more_ than 3 minutes ago). Changing `>=` to `<=` should solve your issue.

Comment: @David i changed but i need to skip the data from the less than 3 minutes and after the last new data within the 3 minute event i need to receive with latest date

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you mean that you need all data within 3 minutes of the last data entry?

Comment: data less than 3 minutes want to be skipped and after remaining data i need to check last 3 minutes data

Comment: because changing the password in less than 3 minutes is not a problem so skipped and after the remaining 3 minutes it is necessary to obtain the details of the event

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting confused... Say there are 5 logs, at 00:00, 00:02, 00:05, 00:06, and 00:08. The current time is 00:10. Which data do you want, and why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247441/discussion-between-david-and-angeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clarified that you need all log entries *within* 3 minutes of program execution time. In that case, you need to add data where `diff <= 180` to your list. Currently (`if diff >= 180:`), your code adds all data where the log time is more than 3 minutes ago. Change that line to `if diff <= 180:` and your code should work fine.